# iOS: ReusableCell changing my data on reuse

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, tableview

I am having an issue with the resusable table cells. I only ever have 11 cells loading, where nearly all the content in them is downloaded, parsed and displayed correctly.

The problem that I am having is that I am shown a UIImageView square with a background colour unique to that row. And when the device is rotated or the table view is scrolled up or down (thus removing unused cells), the colours change to one of the others.

I am not completely sure how to stop this. Currently

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

is being called, and in this it detects the orientation, creates a Cell Identifier, creates the cell and adds things to the cell.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

What are you using as a cell identifier? Use something unique, like

```
NSString *cellIdentifier = someObject.someProperty;
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

where `someObject.someProperty` can be for example item.title

Answer (score 0):

Hm, so this is how dequeuing works.  Even though that conceptually there are 11 rows, actually iOS allows you to cheat and just reuse a few of them, so it works a lot more faster.

You just have to remember that if you asked the table view for a dequeued cell, you still have to reconfigure it so it shows correct data.

If your issue is because that your cells actually does internal processing…  don’t do that.  Move that piece of code elsewhere. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To create tableviewCells you need to use a unique cell Identifier, but all cells in that tableview need the SAME identifier so:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"YOURINDETIFIER";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Now you would setup your cells properties.

If you are using a custom cell, be sure to reconfigure ALL subviews otherwise you will get artefacts from previously used cells.

Can you post what you are doing in cellForRowAtIndexPath ?